# Named capture groups from command line

Tags: regex, bash, macos, shell, perl

I've come up with the following regular expression:

```
\[release(\s+(?<release_type>.*))?\]\n+(?<release_notes>.*)
```

The idea is to parse a commit message for several params:

```
[release minor]

Hello world

- asd
- zxc
```

Matching should result `release_type = 'minor'`, `release_notes = 'Hello world\n…`.

I'm trying to use perl due to old regex engines in macOS.

I've tried:

```sh
perl -ne 'print "$+{release_notes}" while /\[release(\s+(?<release_type>.*))?\]\n+(?<release_notes>.*)/gs;' msg.txt
```

But for some reason, this expression doesn't work as expected.

In fact, even the simpler

```sh
perl -ne 'print "$+{release_notes}" while /\n(?<release_notes>.*)/gs;' msg.txt
```

fails.

This

```sh
perl -ne 'print "$+{release_notes}" while /(?<release_notes>.*)/gs;' msg.txt
```

succeeds and just returns the whole input.

I'm probably missing something simple here, but not sure what it is.

Comment: Can't match across lines (`/s`) unless you "slurp" the file, `perl -0777 -ne'...'`.  Your code works with that as it stands (the first example is also missing `-n`, perhaps a typo)

Comment: @zdim It works! Do you mind posting an explanation what that means as an answer?

Comment: I hope the marked dupe answers explain it well enough.  Your pattern to be matched is spread across multiple lines; in 'normal' `-n` mode only one line at a time is available to the program, so it can't match.  With `-0777` the whole file goes into `$_` and then the regex works as intended

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and quick response!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487100/983912) by @zdim was more helpful than the dup question. Thanks

Comment: Leo Natan -- very glad that a post of mine helped, and thank you for saying it :).  Here is then [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597361/4653379) which spells this out (short and hopefully clear), and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40852382/4653379) with more detail and both a full program and one-liner versions.